# Google App Engine Datastore non-compound indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use indexes on an entity, for example

```
Entity Person
- FirstName String indexed
- LastName String indexed
- Address String indexed
and more indexed properties
```

However, I will query with just an indexed property at a time. I will not make the query by using FirstName *and* LastName as the filter criteria in one query, for example, but just one of them. I had the experience of having the large index size in datastore from the combination of indexed properties in an entity. I want to have my properties indexed individually, not compositely. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create compound indexes - they don't appear by themselves. You do it either manually, or it happens automatically in your development environment when you run a compound query. If you never run these queries, no compound indexes will be created.

You can always check which indexes you have in your project by going to Datastore > Indexes in your Google Cloud Console.